# CsvDate format issue

Tags: java, csv, date, datetime, timestamp

I am trying to write CSV file with SQL time stamp value with the below formate

```
@CsvDate("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a")
private Timestamp inDate;
```

But while writing into CSV file which ever hours are less then 12, format automatically changed to **(m/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss) ex 4/26/2023 10:14:52 AM)**

If date above 12 hrs format is happening correctly
**Ex: 2023-04-22 14:14:52 PM**

Can anyone help me to fix this issue

Comment: With which API?

Comment: @g00se with opencsv

Comment: Version number please

Comment: @g00se 3.8 version

Comment: Shall look if I have time. You know you have a missing double quote above?

Comment: Fine for me with 5.7.1. It might be something else doing that to your data